# Problem Binding Data from Database to a WPF DatagridTemplateColumn (Template Column has a Combobox)

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, datagridtemplatecolumn

I am trying to bind data from a database to a datagrid in WPF using Caliburn.Micro. Caliburn works great with standard text columns but when I try binding the data to a Template Column the data doesnt show up on the screen. For example, in the Material Item column the items show up in the view just by a simple binding. But when I try using a template column with a combobox the same thing doesnt happen. The goal here is to pull data from a database into the view using a Bindablecollection ... Then have a dropdown menu to choose from Material Status, Ordered, Not in Stock, In Stock. Its a really simple Idea to have the past chosen Status (e.g. Not in Stock) changed (e.g. In Stock) and its in many applications. Here is the code and a picture of whats going on.

```
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      CanUserAddRows="False"
                      x:Name="ProjectMaterialList"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMaterialItem}"
                      Margin="10,10,10.333,10">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="MaterialId"
                                        Binding="{Binding MaterialId}"
                                        CanUserResize="False"
                                        Visibility="Hidden" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Project"
                                        Binding="{Binding ProjectName}"
                                        CanUserResize="False"
                                        Width="15*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type"
                                        Width="7*"
                                        Binding="{Binding MaterialType}"
                                        CanUserResize="False" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity"
                                        CanUserResize="False"
                                        Binding="{Binding MaterialQuantity}"
                                        Width="5*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit"
                                        Binding="{Binding MaterialMeasureType}"
                                        CanUserResize="False"
                                        Width="5*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Measure"
                                        Binding="{Binding MaterialMeasure}"
                                        CanUserResize="False"
                                        Width="5*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item"
                                        Binding="{Binding MaterialItem}"
                                        CanUserResize="False"
                                        Width="15*" />
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status"
                                            CanUserResize="False"
                                            Width="11*"
                                            x:Name="MaterialStatus">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding MaterialModel.MaterialStatus }" />

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OrderStatuses }"
                                          SelectedItem="MaterialStatus" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>



                </DataGrid.Columns>

            </DataGrid>
```

[What Happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GaBY.jpg)
[What I Want to happend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdn3H.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you didnt specify an item source for your datagrid ? 
item source should be bound to your observable collection something like:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfMaterial}"
```